# Laravel - I have created new users within a view however when i try to sign into their accounts, "credentials do not exist"

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am a bit stuck.. I am new to laravel so please excuse my lack of knowledge. In my application I have 3 types of users. Admin, Instructor & Student. To begin with I created three users for these roles in my UsersTableSeeder and hashed their passwords.

As I develop my system I have created a 'create users form' that admins only have access to. However when I try to sign in with users created via this form apparently their "credentials do not exist". I am assuming this could be related to the fact that their passwords are not storing as hashed in the DB? I understand this is bad practice but I am not aware how to pass a hashed password in a view/controller. Any advice is appreciated.

create.blade.php;

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="required" for="password">Password</label>
           <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('password') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
               @if($errors->has('password'))
                   <div class="invalid-feedback">
                         {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                   </div>
                @endif
</div>
```

UsersController;

```
public function create()
{
    $roles = Role::all();
    $courses =Course::all();
    return view('admin.user.create', compact('roles', 'courses'));
}
```

I hope my image below helps you understand. The users with hashed passwords where either created via the register form or UsersTableSeeder however I need to be able to successfully create a user via the create form.
[image]

Comment: You hash those passwords too.

Comment: How can i do this in my view? @vivek_23

Comment: Why will you hash passwords in a view blade file? Best way is to make admin create users. Now, users will get an email saying click this link to verify your account and set a password.

Comment: @vivek_23 im just trying to make basic functionality work before progressing onto this..

Comment: But you don't hash passwords in a view blade. You do it in the controller using `Hash::make('your password text');` like how you did for other users.

Comment: yea.. sorry i meant trying to figure out how to hash a password in controller before progressing onto sending emails to users to reset their password .. as I want the admin to be the only one to create a new user and enter a generic password but i need to figure out how to hash this in the create method in UsersController.

Comment: If you are making admin to set a password for a user and then making the user to reset his password, then it's double work and doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to hash the passwords. That is most likely your issue. So, in your controller method, you will need something like this...

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = 'user';
$user->email = 'user@user.com;
$user->password = Hash::make('password');
$user->save();
```

If you have any custom fields, follow the same principle with each of them.

Comment: I would recommend using this method rather than my answer above of creating the user then updating the password....

Comment: Thanks for this, is there a way to get the password entered by admin in the create form and store as hashed?

Comment: Not sure that I am following your question. What I would suggest is when you create the new user in the create form, on submitting the form for the new user call a controller method on your user controller. You theoretically could create the user from the blade file, but I would not advise that you do it...

Answer (score 0):

you are correct - the unhashed passwords will cause you a lot of problems. The easiest fix is simply to hash the passwords when creating the users. There is a facade for hashing built into laravel so on create:

```
$hashedPassword = Hash::make($request->request->get('password'))
$user = User::create($request->all());
User::where('email', $user->email)->update(['password' => $hashedPassword]);
```

Please note this code is ripped from an api I wrote a while back where a request was sent to the server with the parameters needed to create a user (think it was just email/password). But yeah essentially the steps are:

1) Create hashed password using the Hash facade and the plaintext password

2) Create your user

3) Immediately update your user with the hashed password.

This means you can also use Hash::check() method when users are logging in:

```
        if (Hash::check($request->input('password'), User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first()->password)) {
            // success, user logs in 
        } else {
            $msg = ['error' => true, 'message' => 'Incorrect password'];

            return response()->json($msg, 200);
        }
```

Hope this helps!